# How to annotate a method that returns tuple to enable null-state static analysis

Tags: c#

I have a few methods like this.

```
public static (bool, Type?) GetType(string name)
{
    if (NameToTypeMap.TryGetValue(name, out var type))
    {
        return (true, type);
    }

    return (false, null);
}
```

(the internal implementation does not always fall back to the `TryGetValue`. It differs from case to case. Important here is the shape of the method)

**Question**: is it possible to annotate the method so that when the first value of the tuple is `true`, then the second value of the tuple is not `null`?

I'm looking for something similar to what we have for `TryXYZ` methods (with the attribute `[NotNullWhen(true)]`) e.g.

```
bool TryGetMessage(string key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out string? message)
{
    if (_messageMap.ContainsKey(key))
        message = _messageMap[key];
    else
        message = null;
    return message is not null;
}
```

I have tried a few attributes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis, but without success.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like `Nullable<T>`, with the optional value and `HasValue` property

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Well, not really. The `Nullable<T>` works with the structs. Here the `T` is a reference type

Comment: Is `T` always a reference type? Is it possible for the method to return `(true, null)`? It looks like the boolean is just there for convenience, but if you have nullable analysis turned on then I think it's much more intuitive to return `T?` and leave the null check to the consumer

Comment: I think you are right. the mechanics of `T?` seem to be closer to the C# nature. Using tuples is a bad choice. Thanks